# How can I record my screen, with sound, and encode it live?

Tags: video-streaming, video-conversion, fraps

I need to record about two hours of streaming video. Is there a way to encode the video directly ?

I've used fraps, but the files created are just enormous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on WHAT you want to record.
For **games**, try **Dxtory**. It can encode your videos directly (unlike FRAPS).
For **desktop**, try **Camtasia Studio**. At least I used this one, it has excellent video editing and encoding capabilities. But there are many free recorders out there too.

Comment: Dxtory looks nice, but is it only for games ? In my case I want to record a video stream, in flash on a website.

Comment: @Manu - Why do you want to use Flash?  I suggest you use YouTube and embed the video in your site.  It is much easier to work with and you don't force Exploit flash 10.x on everyone.

Comment: You misunderstood. There's a website that shows a 2-hour long video (in streaming, in a flash player), and I would like to record it. Doesn't have to be HD or anything, but I don't have the disk space to store 2 hours of unencoded video.

Comment: I think you should use a simple free recorder for a flash video. Or Camtasia if you can afford. Anything will be fine for a flash stream. Seriously. | Like http://camstudio.org/ . I only used Camstudio so far besides Camtasia.